# Do I really need one of those TAX IDS: SSN, ITIN, EIN?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

I am not familiar with taxes. I've just enrolled developer program and am about to start sell the app through App Store. My country is **Poland**, I am individual person, I do not have company.

I need to fill **Certificate of Foreign Status of Beneficial Owner**, and I stacked on first part of this form: **Part I: Identification of Beneficial Owner**.

The question is:

**Do I really need one of those TAX IDS: SSN, ITIN, EIN?**

The screenshot below simply describes my problem:

[image]

Comment: What did you do since 6 years?

Comment: I have filled everything what they wanted from me;) I successfully sell the app through AppStore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what Apple would do if you declined to offer those numbers. You could reach out to their support or just go ahead and register with the US government for an EIN if you choose to register as a foreign company or an ITIN if you wish to register as a foreign individual.

Please don't take advice over the internet for tax / legal issues, though. You'll really want to get someone that knows about the law and/or finance to help you choose and fill out these legally binding forms.